# access: centering controls on report

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

thanks to hansup i have a bunch of fields on a report, i would like to center the enter block of controls. how do i do it?

Comment: This is not by any stretch of the imagination a programming question. It belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: +1 for mr fenton cause he's the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access forms and reports aren't intended to do automatic resizing and layout. Unless you have very special requirements, you can just make sure that the report canvas is the same width as the printed page, then manually position the controls in the center of the canvas (in design view).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if I need to center something on the report, I'll make the control as wide as the report is, then center the text in the control.

You could figure out where the center of your report is, then figure out where the center of the control is and align the center of the control with the center of the report. I generally find this is more effort than I want when I can do the above option.

Comment: what if u have two controls side by side

Comment: Then you're going to have to figure out where the center of the report is and align them to that spot. I don't know of any way around that one.